# How to count the number of occurence of a key in pyspark dataframe (2.1.0)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-2.0

## Context

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
col1 | col2 | col3
a    | toto | 1
a    | toto | 2
a    | toto | 45
a    | toto | 789
a    | toto | 456
b    | titi | 4
b    | titi | 8
```

With `col1` as a primary key.

I would like to know how I can determine which key in `col1` has less than 5 occurences in the dataframe.

So the output should be:

```
col1 | col2 | col3
b    | titi |
```

So far, i came up with the following solution:

```
anc_ref_window = Window.partitionBy("col1")
df\
    .withColumn("temp_one", lit(1)) \
    .withColumn("count", sum(col("temp_one")).over(anc_ref_window)) \
    .drop("temp_one") \
    .filter(col("count") < 5) \
    .drop("count") \
    .show()
```

Which gives the following results:

```
col1 | col2 | col3
b    | titi | 4
b    | titi | 8
```

## Questions

1 - Is it the correct approach to the problem ?

2 - How can I only get the expected output ? With my version of pyspark (2.1.0), it seems there is no such mecanism like `select distinct col1,col2` as I would do via Impala (for example).

Edit:

The output value in col3 does not matter for me.

Comment: what is your expected output value in col3?

Comment: @koiralo It does not matter in my case.

Comment: @koiralo The spark doc does not say I can pass parameters (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.distinct) and when I try with column names as different params or as a list, the interpreter tells me distinct takes only one positional argument (self I guess), but two are given.

Comment: sorry, take a look at dropDuplicates, you should be able to pass the columns as well

Comment: Woops, you posted while I wrote my answer. Feel free to write your own, so that I accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@koilaro oriented me towards `distinct`. However it does not provide the capacity to indicate column names in `pyspark 2.1.0`.

However, `dropDuplicates` does the job:

```
df\
    .withColumn("temp_one", lit(1)) \
    .withColumn("count", sum(col("temp_one")).over(anc_ref_window)) \
    .drop("temp_one") \
    .filter(col("count") < 5) \
    .drop("count") \
    .dropDuplicates(["col1"])
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach :

```
df_lessthan5 = df.groupBy(col("col1")).count() \
                 .filter(col("count") < 5) \
                 .drop(col("count"))

df_distinct = df.drop(col("col3")).distinct()

result = df_distinct.join(df_lessthan5, ['col1'], 'inner')
```

result :

```
result.show()
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   b|titi|
+----+----+
```

---

Performance wise if you compare with window operation :

If you are sure that your windowed column (col1) is not highly skewed, then it will be slightly better or comparable with this GroupBy solution.

But if your `col1` is highly skewed , then it will not be parallelized properly and 1 task has to do all the major operation. In this case, you should go for groupBy + join

Comment: My data is skewed and your solution is way faster (3/4 minutes less on a very small sample of data). Could you explain why ? From my basic understanding, groupBy or window, the rows with the same key would be grouped together in a task, which would then (for skewed data) induce one task only and probably shuffle as well. Why is groupBy faster ?

Comment: PS: well, with all the computation, it is not faster finally. But my question still stands :P

Comment: As per my understanding for window , the rows have to shuffled and brought to a single partition first and then operation is applied . That is why groupBy is faster vs window specifically.